# XAMPP Server Error: End of script output before headers using php

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

My php code:

```
 <?php
  function mail_man($person)
  {
    $html = "";
    $url = "members.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die ("Can't connect to URL");
    foreach ($xml->listgroup as $group)
    {
      $user = $group->user;
      if ($user == $person)
      {
        $mail_list = $group->list;
        foreach ($mail_list as $mail)
        {
          $html .= "<li>
                      <a href='https://example.com/$mail'
                      target='_blank' title='Roster List For: $mail'>$mail</a>
                      <a href='mailto:$mail@example.com'
                      title='Email $mail'>Email</a>
                      </li>";
        }
      }
    }
  echo "<ul>$html</ul>";
}
mail_man("somebody");
echo "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
?>
```

Trying to open using button on basic example website:

```
<h1>Mailman</h1>
<form action="./mail.php" method="post">
  <input type="Submit" value="Run mailman search.">
</form>
```

And got:
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
End of script output before headers: newphp.html

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.26 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.0.21 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

I used chmod 755 on both files. Any other ideas?

Edit:
Removed echo content line does nothing.
Output from php-error-log says: "Trying to get property of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mail.php on line 7." However, I can open localhost/mail.php fine and it gives the output I'm looking for.

Comment: Why are you echoing your Content-Type at the end?

Comment: Another failed attempt to fix the problem. Tried removing that line and doesn't fix it.

Comment: One other thing. You should never use `echo` in a function. Use `return` and then use `echo` outside the function.

Comment: don't echo Content-Type - that's a header for serverside, not to be displayed front-end. also, I recommend concatting variables, including them in strings is bad for readability. You should as Difster said, return your outcome instead of echo'ing it

Comment: Thanks for tip. Changed but still gives same error.

Comment: @Jaquizmo then you're doing something really wrong in how you're executing your script